What is the story of Kali Ramayana? Is it a true story or just fiction?
I recently came across The Kali Ramayana book, and one character that stood out to me was Shyam. The narrative describes Shyam as crucial in Kali Yuga, supporting Kalki in the Dharma Yudha. I’m curious if there is any mention of Shyam in traditional Hindu scriptures, Itihasas, or Puranas.
I would love to hear from those who are well-versed in these texts. Does Shyam have a historical or mythological basis, or is he a mythical character introduced in that story?
